# Cordova UWP build can’t access the internet (outside of localhost)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

I have a Cordova (Ionic >=2) UWP application that connects to a backend REST service via https. This works fine in ionic serve, and also when deployed and running on iOS and Android.

I have finally got a UWP build to install on my local desktop dev machine (Windows 10). I’ve double clicked the .appx file to install, and then app successfully installs and displays

```
 Capabilities:

   Access your Internet connection
```

When I run a test http command it has, it can connect to localhost, but not to a remote server using https (and a published DNS names that works everywhere else).

If I build in debug and run in VS, the error returned by the http.get just shows the following:

[image]

So just status 0 and no status description. Probably a security problem?

How can I diagnose this?

### Update

I installed Fiddler, and this reports the following:

```
 HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - DNS Lookup Failed
 Date: Thu, 03 Aug 2017 00:58:47 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Connection: close
 Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
 Timestamp: 08:58:47.799
```

So is pointing to a DNS lookup problem?

Comment: Does it work on Android and iOS?

Comment: Yes it works on both iOS and Android, as well as when I run it (on the same Dev machine) just via Ionic serve.

Comment: @peterc I have the same issue, do you found a solution?

Comment: Hi, yes the key for me was I had to add the capability `Private Networks (Client & Server)` and I did this using `cordova plugin add cordova-windows-capability-localnetwork`> Perhaps I better add this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key for me here was I needed `Private Networks (Client & Server)`

The following did this for me...

```
cordova plugin add cordova-windows-capability-localnetwork
```